# Setting different list_display options for different models in the same admin

Tags: python, django

I have multiple models registered to an admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User, Claim, Caption

@admin.register(User, Claim, Caption)
class ScopeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

I want to set the list_display property but that value is different for each model. Is there a way around this or do I need to create an admin per model?

Comment: You have to use same admin class for all models?

Comment: yes I believe you need to create an admin per model.